# Why is scrollToEnd() not working on Android?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I currently have it set such that when the user opens the keyboard it scrolls to the bottom when the scroll view shrinks.

```
<ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
          ref={(ref) => (this.scrollView = ref)}
>
 <TextInput
     onFocus = {this.scrollDown}
/>

scrollDown = () => {
     this.scrollView.scrollToEnd();
}
```

This works on IOS perfectly fine, but doesn't seem to be working on Android.

Android:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh50T.jpg

iOS:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFPcb.jpg

Comment: Please include screenshot of both IoS and Android behaviour so that we can analyse the difference.

Answer (score 0):

--Update--

After looking your record, it doesn't seems caused by `scrollToEnd`.

What you need may be [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview)

> It can automatically adjust either its height, position, or bottom padding based on the keyboard height.

```js
const keyboardVerticalOffset = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : 0  //update 2 something like this
...
 <KeyboardAvoidingView
  behavior='position'                                          //update 2
  keyboardVerticalOffset={keyboardVerticalOffset}              //update 2
  style={styles.container}
>
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
    <View style={styles.inner}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>Header</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder="Username" style={styles.textInput} />
      <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={() => null} />
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: yeah I currently have a KeyboardAvoidingView that wrapped the content in the post. The view shortens the height of the scroll view without keeping the relative scroll position. It doesn't get cut off like the video hints at.

Comment: You could use [behavior](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview#behavior) to adjust it

Comment: I have update my answer again, you could adjust value by your project.